# How to schedule a shell script in Linux centos?

Tags: linux, shell, scheduling

I have a script that I need to schedule on daily basis. How can I schedule a script in centos. Like I want to run that script everyday at 10 AM and can I store the output of the script in a log file.

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To schedule a script, you'll need to use `crontab`. You can add a schedule entry by doing:

```
crontab -e
```

Once you are inside, the `cron` accepts pattern in the form:

```
<Minute> <Hour> <Day> <Month> <Day of Week> <Command>
```

So a correct crontab entry for 10am would be

```
0 10 * * * /path/to/script
```

If you want to capture the output you can specify the logfile inside `cron` like

```
0 10 * * * /path/to/script > /path/to/log/output.log
```

Just ensure you put a `she-bang` header in your script. Alternatively, you can specify the shell interpreter inside `cron` by saying:

```
0 10 * * * bash /path/to/script > /path/to/log/output.log
```

Answer (score 2):

```
crontab -e
```

add an entry

```
0 10 * * * sh your_script.sh > your_log_file
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is these * mean ?

Comment: when I am writing this : `crontab -e
no crontab for root - using an empty one`  !!! Is this an error

Comment: first * means all days of the week, second * means all months in an year, third * means all days of the week . That means we care only about time i.e at 0 mins, 10 hrs irrespective of other constraints. Also I think no crontab for root means there are no cron jobs scheduled. Initial part of the newly created file will be commented, you need to add your job after the comments.